# Largest Contentful Paint Error on Google Chrome Lighthouse Report

Tags: performance, next.js, lighthouse, preconnect, largest-contentful-paint

I'm receiving an Error ! for the Performance tab on the Google Chrome Lighthouse report.
I tried to fix but I was unable to, any advice?

This is the following error:
`Largest Contentful Paint Error! The page did not display content that qualifies as a Largest Contentful Paint (LCP). Ensure the page has a valid LCP element and then try again. (NO_LCP)`

On Diagnostics, it has an error:

`Preconnect to required origins Error! Consider adding preconnect or dns-prefetch resource hints to establish early connections to important third-party origins. Learn how to preconnect to required origins.FCPLCP. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/lighthouse/performance/uses-rel-preconnect/?utm_source=lighthouse&utm_medium=devtools`
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tooEl.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbZoA.png)

I added the following link tag to my app.js file but it did not fix the error.
I added it to preconnect to google fonts, although I am using NextJS's next/font.
Resource https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/google-font-preconnect
`<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />`
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tquAM.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWMc8.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting! I think this error is a combination of two things:

- the background image covers the full screen
- the text content fades in

According to https://web.dev/lcp/#what-elements-are-considered, fullscreen images (eg background images) are excluded from being considered LCP elements. Also, elements with 0 opacity are excluded.

Given that all of the page contents are either a fullscreen background image or faded in, nothing qualifies as the LCP element.

One could argue that the "We Empower Ideas" `H1` should be counted as the LCP element after it fades in, but it would need to be repainted first.

More info in this article: https://www.debugbear.com/blog/opacity-animation-poor-lcp

So I'd suggest removing the fade effect from the text to ensure that it gets counted as the LCP element accurately.

Comment: Thanks so much!! Updating the h1 so that it's not transparent initially fixed it.